# Google maps app crashes after phone restart

Tags: android, google-maps, crash, maps

I made a Google map application and it worked all until I restarted my phone. Every time I try to launch my app it crashes and I don't know why. I think it cant get the location or the map won't create?

```
public class GoogleMapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener, OnMapReadyCallback{

    private GoogleMap mMap; // Might be null if Google Play services APK is not available.

    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private LocationRequest myLocationRequest;
    public static final String TAG = GoogleMapsActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    double latitude2;
    double longitude2;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_google_maps);
        setUpMapIfNeeded();



        // Macht andere GooglePlayServices einfacher zu benutzen
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();

        // Baut das LocationRequest objekt
        myLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
                .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
                .setInterval(10 * 1000)        // 10 seconds, in millisekunden
                .setFastestInterval(1 * 1000); // 1 second, in millisekunden
    }


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }




    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
        if (mMap == null) {
            // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
            mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                    .getMap();
            // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
            if (mMap != null) {
                setUpMap();
            }
        }
    }



    private void setUpMap() {


    }


    private void handleNewLocation(Location location) {

        /*Marker flora = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(florakoords)
                .title("Castle")
                .alpha(0.7f));
      */


        Log.d(TAG, location.toString());


        double currentLatitude = location.getLatitude();
        double currentLongitude = location.getLongitude();

        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(currentLatitude, currentLongitude);

        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

        double entfernung = vergleicheDistanz(currentLatitude, currentLongitude, latitude2, longitude2);


        //Rundet Entfernung
        entfernung = Math.round(100.0 * entfernung)/100.0;

        String entfernungString = String.valueOf(entfernung);

       // flora.setSnippet(entfernungString);
       // flora.showInfoWindow();


        if (entfernung <= 200.0){


            new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setMessage("Noch 200 Meter bis zum Auto!").setNeutralButton("ok",null).show();


        }

        else {

            new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setMessage("Über 200 meter bis zum Auto").setNeutralButton("ok",null).show();

        }

    }


    public static float vergleicheDistanz(double latitude, double longitude, double latitude2, double longitude2) {


        Location locationA = new Location("point A");
        locationA.setLatitude(latitude);
        locationA.setLongitude(longitude);

        Location locationB = new Location("point B");
        locationB.setLatitude(latitude2);
        locationB.setLongitude(longitude2);

        float distanz = locationA.distanceTo(locationB);

        return distanz;
    }


    public void getsavedKoords(){


        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

        String latitude = extras.getString("latitude");

        String longitude = extras.getString("longitude");

        double latitude2 = Double.valueOf(latitude);
        double longitude2 = Double.valueOf(longitude);

        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude2,longitude2)).title("Saved"));

    }


    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

        // Erlaubt google maps meine Location zu nutzen
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        // Ist dazu da das LocationManager aus getSystemService "importiert" wird wofür LocationManager da ist keine ahnung ...
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);


        // Create a criteria object to retrieve provider (Braucht man um später seine Location zu bestimmen)
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

        String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);


        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        if (location == null) {
            // request location update!!
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates (LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,1000, 0,  this);

        }
        else {

            double lat = location.getLatitude();
            double lon = location.getLongitude();

            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat,lon);

            getsavedKoords();


            // Show the current location in Google Map (Zeigt die jetzige Location in einer "animation")
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

            // Zoom in the Google Map (Zoomt zu unserer Position, Erschafft danach einen Marker an unserer Position mit der Nachricht "Du bist hier")
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(14));


            // Zoom in the Google Map (Zoomt zu unserer Position, Erschafft danach einen Marker an unserer Position mit der Nachricht "Du bist hier")
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(14));
        }


    }
}


My MainActivity 

    public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    public String saved = "false";

    private Button ParkMyCar;
    private Button BringMeBackToMyCar;
    private Button DeleteMyCar;


    private SharedPreferences preferences;
    private SharedPreferences.Editor preferencesEditor;

    private static final String SavedKoordsFile = "savedKoords";
    private static final int PREFERENCE_MODE_PRIVATE = 0;

    private SharedPreferences FilepreferencesSetting;
    private SharedPreferences.Editor FilepreferencesEditor;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        ParkMyCar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ParkMyCar);
        ParkMyCar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


            @Override


            public void onClick(View ParkMyCar) {

                LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

                Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

                String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

                Location myLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

                double lat = myLocation.getLatitude();
                double lon = myLocation.getLongitude();

                String savedlatitude = String.valueOf(lat);
                String savedlongitude = String.valueOf(lon);

                saved = "true";

                FilepreferencesSetting = getSharedPreferences(SavedKoordsFile, PREFERENCE_MODE_PRIVATE);
                FilepreferencesEditor = FilepreferencesSetting.edit();


                // preferencesEditor.putString("latitude",savedlatitude); Schreibt die variable in einen textfile
                FilepreferencesEditor.putString("latitude", savedlatitude);
                FilepreferencesEditor.putString("longitude", savedlongitude);
                FilepreferencesEditor.putString("saved", saved);


                //Speichert dad ganze
                FilepreferencesEditor.commit();

                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, GoogleMapsActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("latitude", savedlatitude);
                i.putExtra("longitude", savedlongitude);
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });



        BringMeBackToMyCar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.BringMeBackToMyCar);
        BringMeBackToMyCar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


            @Override


            public void onClick(View v) {

               FilepreferencesSetting = getSharedPreferences(SavedKoordsFile, PREFERENCE_MODE_PRIVATE);


                String LoadedLat = FilepreferencesSetting.getString("latitude","DEFAULT");
                String LoadedLon = FilepreferencesSetting.getString("longitude", "DEFAULT");
                String saved = FilepreferencesSetting.getString("saved", "DEFAULT");

                if (saved == "true") {


                    FilepreferencesSetting = getSharedPreferences(SavedKoordsFile, PREFERENCE_MODE_PRIVATE);
                    FilepreferencesEditor = FilepreferencesSetting.edit();

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), LoadedLat + " " + LoadedLon, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                    FilepreferencesEditor.putString("LoadedLat", LoadedLat);
                    FilepreferencesEditor.putString("LoadedLon", LoadedLon);

                    FilepreferencesEditor.commit();

                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoadedGoogleMaps.class);
                    i.putExtra("LoadedLat", LoadedLat);
                    i.putExtra("LoadedLon", LoadedLon);

                    startActivity(i);

                }
                else {


                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Keine Position vorhanden!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                }

            }

        });


        DeleteMyCar = (Button)findViewById(R.id.DeleteMyCar);
        DeleteMyCar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


            @Override


            public void onClick(View v) {


                FilepreferencesSetting = getSharedPreferences(SavedKoordsFile, PREFERENCE_MODE_PRIVATE);
                FilepreferencesEditor = FilepreferencesSetting.edit();

                String saved = FilepreferencesSetting.getString("saved", "DEFAULT");

                if (saved == "true") {

                    FilepreferencesEditor.clear();
                    FilepreferencesEditor.commit();

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Position gelöscht", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    FilepreferencesSetting = getSharedPreferences(SavedKoordsFile, PREFERENCE_MODE_PRIVATE);
                    FilepreferencesEditor = FilepreferencesSetting.edit();

                    saved = "false";

                    FilepreferencesEditor.putString("saved", saved);

                }

                else{

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Die Position wurde schon gelöscht", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }

                }

        });

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

Comment: Please post the LogCat.

Comment: @zackygaurav ok here it is :)

Answer (score 0):

Add below permissions in Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
```

Comment: i added it ... but still crahses with the same logcat .... Logcat says something about double android.location.Location.getLatitude() ....

Comment: MainActivity: Line No. 74 has error. Check that out or post MainActivity. Moreover put your device's GPS on **High Accuracy**